# Show delete and edit buttons for custom filters on mouseover

Tags: feature-request, custom-filters

Currently, when you go to delete or edit a custom filter, you have to click on it (which applies the filter again) to get the Edit/Delete buttons to show:

[image]

I propose making those buttons appear when you move your mouse over the filter, so you can edit/delete without re-applying the filter and reloading the page.

Comment: Some screenshots would be useful.

Comment: @bad_coder Yep, I'll get 'em.

Comment: Hey @bad_coder, I only put in one, I could try making a GIF to show you, but it may take a minute.

Comment: I understand now, an animated GIF is always cool but in this case perhaps it's better to let users try themselves.